# How to hide page name in rewrite rules in Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to hide page name from url using rewrite rules in Nginx. but its not working, please see the below example

Actual url: `https://super30.net/referal.php?uid=999999` Needed url: `https://super30.net/999999`

I tried below code

```
location = / {
      rewrite ^/referal/(.*)$ /referal.php?uid=$1 last;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `location` only matches the single URL `/`, and the `rewrite` statement only matches URLs that begin with `/referal/`.

If you need to match URLs that contain only digits, you could use:

```
rewrite ^/(\d+)$ /referal.php?uid=$1 last;
```

You can place this in the `server` block, or the existing `location /` block. The `location = /` block will not work.